# docker image running but can't access rest endpoint in spring boot application

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I have created a spring-boot application, when build and run it using maven it was working success full. But when i ran docker of my app it was running in the console but i can't access any REST endpoint browser is giving page not found error.

here is the content of my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 5555:5555
ADD /hotline-api/target/hotline-api.jar hotline-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","hotline-api.jar","--spring.profiles.active=test"]
```

Comment: Can you please upload the startup logs

Comment: How do you run the image? What is the command that you use?

Comment: docker run -p 5555:5555 my_image_name

Comment: do you have `server.port=5555` in your `application.properties` or `application-test.properties`?

Comment: yes the server port is 5555 and when i ran the .jar using java -jar it is working successfully

Answer (score 6):

You also need to **publish the port** while running your image

```
docker run -p 5555:5555 IMAGE_NAME
```

---

Make sure you also expose the same port from your `properties` file based on your profile (default/dev/test).

Comment: Hi Mehraj, i did the same way

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue with docker setup on windows 7 using docker machine. The REST endpoint is mapped to the ip address of the docker machine. I solved it by getting the docker machine ip using:

> docker-machine ip

Then use this to access the REST endpoints, like:

> 192.168.12.100:8080/login

Answer (score 0):

Add more parameter :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","hotline-api.jar","--spring.profiles.active=test","--server.port=5555"]
```

Then build container:

```
docker run -p 5555:5555 IMAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the jar at `/hotline-api/target/hotline-api.jar`
And also make sure that the latest jar is present by doing a gradle or maven build.
The jar won't be updated if you do a boot run which means your newly configured end point will not be present in the jar and hence not in the docker image